# Gracefully postpone QueueTrigger

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-webjobssdk

I'am currently using the WebJobs SDK to consume messages issued in queue.

My method as one parameter with the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.QueueTrigger(...)] attribute and is triggered alright.
In some circumstances, the method can process the message but from time to time, I would prefer that it reject the message until a critical resource becomes available.

I tryed to throw an exception in this case, but contrary to what the reference says, the queue trigger is fired again immediately (apparently not waiting the lease time).

Is there a way to gracefuly postpone the message handling ?
Would it be safe just to freeze the thread waiting for critical resource ?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: << ...the queue trigger is fired again immediately (apparently not waiting the lease time). >> You might be seeing this because of what's stated here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mustafakasap/2015/12/26/azure-webjobs-jobhostconfiguration/: (assuming it's correct): "Unless there exist other messages waiting in the queue that are not in concurrent processing stage, there is no time interval between trials! So if there exists enough resources, retry occurs immediately."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can postpone a message in current version.

**Possible workaround**

You can re-add the same message with delay and to avoid duplicates you can set your `MaxDequeueCount` to `1`, this will send *failing* message straight to *poison* queue after exception:

```
        JobHostConfiguration configuration = new JobHostConfiguration();
        configuration.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
```

and message processor - re-add your message with delay and throw exception:

```
    public static void ProcessMessage([QueueTrigger("resource-heavy-queue")] string message, [Queue("resource-heavy-queue")]  CloudQueue originalQueue)
    {
        if ( /*Resource unavaliable*/)
        {
            var messageToReAdd = new CloudQueueMessage(message);
            originalQueue.AddMessage(messageToReAdd, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            throw new ResourcesNotAvailableException();
        }
    }
```

This way you can implement some kind of back-off strategy for your resource. Unfortunately you have to manually deal with some problems:

- Handling poison messages - if you keep re-adding the same message you can end up in infinite loop, so you have to extend your message model to carry `NumberOfRetries` and increment it every time you re-add it
- Message `Id` and `InsertionTime` will be different after every *re-add* so you can't rely on them.

Comment: Well message time stamp is somewhat important to me. If I readd I would have to persist original time stamp in some way

Comment: You can use Decorator pattern and re-add decorated version of your message with *original timestamp* and for example *number of retries*. This way you don't have to persist it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not possible to postpone a trigger. What you want is a multitrigger (trigger when the message AND the resource are available) that the Azure WebJobs SDK doesn't have

There are a few workarounds. You could freeze the thread if **all** messages in that queue require the critical resources - you are implementing a semaphore - otherwise, it gets tricky to schedule because the SDK will not process new messages if you reach the maximum number of functions running in parallel.

What I would do instead of triggering on the queue message is trigger on the critical resource. When the resource is available, it puts a message in another queue and, only then, check to see if there are any messages to process that require the resource.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't trigger on critical resource! What I'm doing for the moment is freeze the thread and periodically retry to lock the resource. There's a limit to the retry count: when it's reached I throw & come back to default poisoned message management.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing in this situation is to have an `ICollector` for the same Queue I am triggered from like

```
public static async Task HandleMessagesAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueName%")] BrokeredMessage message, [ServiceBus("%QueueName%")]ICollector<BrokeredMessage> queue, TextWriter logger)
```

(the `%QueueName%` notation makes the SDK fetch the value from the app.config)

Then in the handler I am doing something like

```
if (needToWait)
{
    var delayedMessage = new BrokeredMessage(originalMessageBody) { Label = originalLabel, MessageId = originalMessageId, ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + this.ExecutionDelay };
    queue.Add(delayedMessage);
    return;
}
```

That way the current message gets completed, but a new one with the same properties is scheduled to be delivered after the defined timeout.

No threads are blocked in the making of this program.